# Can you open LinkedIn iOS 8 share extension?

Tags: ios8, linkedin-api

With iOS 8 LinkedIn implemented Share Extension. I know there is no framework for sharing, but i was wondering if i can open the Share Extension from within the app but not from the QLPreviewController. We have created a custom share screen and for now we just open a web view.

Thank You;

Answer (score 1):

The iOS 8 extensions cannot be presented in a custom share screen. You absolutely have to use UIActivity​View​Controller in order for the share/action extensions to appear.

For the linkedin extension to appear in your app, you have to:

1. Use UIActivitViewController to present the share sheet

and the users have to:

2. Open the share sheet
3. Select More
4. Enable (flip the switch to green) for the linkedin extension

Comment: Thank you for your response but i was looking for a faster way. I just wanted to skip the share sheet and just open the extension.

Comment: There is no way to skip as it is the only point of entry possible for share extensions. Apple took this approach to ensure sandboxing remains intact (for security and UX) Also, if users dont explicitly enable the linkedin extension, it will not be available in your app and there is no way around that.

Answer (score 0):

Before `iOS 11`, you can create the  `SLComposeViewController` like this

```
[SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:@"com.linkedin.LinkedIn.ShareExtension"];
```